# How to make nvm recognise a node.js version installed prior to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, nvm

I had installed a node.js version on Linux before installing nvm. nvm is not recognising that node version that was installed prior to it. Can I make nvm recognise it without having to uninstall and re-install the node version?

Thank you. J

Comment: Even if possible, nvm installs versions of node in a directory different from where direct installation of node would usually go. If you don’t _need_ your direct installation of node just use nvm install and avoid duplicate binaries.

Comment: Thank you @OFRBG I actually do need my direct installation, but was trying to avoid uninstalling and re-installing it in case it creates issues. I had installed it some time ago and now wish to install the latest version of node without touching the older one.

Comment: I don’t think nvm let’s you link your own. You could add both bins to your PATH and alias/create symlink your direct installation as “node-local”.